# How to trigger an observable stream which be used as async pipe?

Tags: angular, observable, behaviorsubject

I have a context where I need to fetch data in parallel along side with angular group tab. When a tab opened, I'd like it to fetch data, show loading in process, show data when it's done fetching, or show error (if any), all upon html. And I wish to trigger that process freely with a triggerer

My component.ts:

```
private queryInboxTriggerObs: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('');
queryInboxTrigger$ = this.queryInboxTriggerObs.asObservable();

ngOnInit() {
    const getInbox$ = timer(6e3).pipe(tap(res => console.log(`getInbox$`, res)), map(() => ({ inbox: 1 }))); // fake api
    this.timeout$ = timer(5e3).pipe(take(1), map(() => { throw new Error('timeout!!!') }));
    this.queryInbox$ = concat(
        of({ type: 'start' }),
        of(1).pipe(
            switchMap(() => race(this.timeout$, getInbox$)),
            tap(res => console.log(`race`, res)),
            map(res => ({type: 'finish', value: res}))
        )
    );
    this.inbox$ = this.queryInboxTrigger$.pipe(exhaustMap(() => this.queryInbox$));

    this.initInbox();
}

initInbox() {
    this.queryInboxTriggerObs.next('');
}

onLoadInboxClick() {
    this.initInbox();
}
```

where using `exhaustMap` because I do not wish to restart process when tab switched, keep it going till it's done,`getInbox$` is my http request, `inbox$` is my async observable, and `queryInboxTrigger$` is my trigger to the process.

inside `initInbox()`, I only call `this.queryInboxTriggerObs.next('');`, and I expect it to trigger my fetching data process everytime I call `initInbox()`, like within `onLoadInboxClick`. Unfortunately, my trigger only work the first time on ngOnInit, I cannot trigger the process again by keep doing `this.queryInboxTriggerObs.next('')` by clicking or switching tab, I need help here. For example, when `timeout$` emits value, my html shows text load data again and `onLoadInboxClick` called, I expect `queryInbox$` to run again

My component.html

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" (selectedIndexChange)="selectedIndexChange($event)">
<mat-tab label="Inbox">
    <ng-container *ngIf="inbox$ | withLoading | async as inbox">
        <ng-container *ngIf="inbox.error">
            <p>Data not found. <a (click)="onLoadInboxClick()">Try again</a></p>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="inbox.value">
            <span>Inbox: {{ inbox.value.inbox }}</span>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="inbox.loading">
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Tab 3">Content 3</mat-tab>
```

and my custom async pipe

```
transform(value: any): any {
    return isObservable(value)
            ? value.pipe(
                map((val: any) => {
                    return {
                        loading: val.type === 'start',
                        value: val.type ? val.value : val
                    }
                }),
                startWith({ loading: true }),
                catchError(error => of({ loading: false, error }))
            )
            : value;
}
```

Comment: i don't see issues with your code... is your intention to "trigger" the observable from other components?

Comment: @TheFabio My issue is I cannot restart queryInbox$ again when I do this.queryInboxTriggerObs.next('');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like my custom pipe is causing problem. When I update code like this

```
this.queryInbox$ = concat(
        of({ type: 'start' }),
        of(1).pipe(
            switchMap(() => race(this.timeout$, this.getInbox$)),
            tap(res => console.log(`race`, res)),
            map(res => ({type: 'finish', value: res})),
            catchError(err => of({ type: 'error' }))
        )
    );
```

and update my html accordingly (remove withLoading pipe)

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="start" (selectedIndexChange)="selectedIndexChange($event)">
<mat-tab label="Hộp thư đến">
    <ng-container *ngIf="inbox$ | async as inbox">
        <ng-container *ngIf="inbox.type === 'error'">
            <p>Data not found. <a (click)="onLoadInboxClick()">Try again</a></p>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="inbox.type === 'finish'">
            <span>Inbox: {{ inbox.value.inbox }}</span>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="inbox.type === 'start'">
            <p>Loading...</p>
        </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Hộp thư đi">Content 2</mat-tab>
<mat-tab label="Tạo thư mới">Content 3</mat-tab>
```

Everything works as expected.